# Text on a rectangle kills the rectangle's hover effect

Tags: css, svg, hover

I have several svg rectangles with an hover effect, the background-color of the rectangles gets changed when the mouse is over them. The hover effect is set via css:

```
.myclass:hover {
    fill: rgb(255,128,0);
}
```

Apart from that, text is placed above each of the rectangles. A pair of text and rectangle define a group.

```
<g>
    <rect class="myclass" x="10" y="10" width="40" height="40" />
    <text x="30" y="40" font-family="Verdana" font-size="10" fill="blue">ESC</text>
</g>
```

The hover effect works fine, but only if the cursor is not exactly above the text. If it is exactly above the text, then the hover effect vanishes.

How could I fix that?

Here a screenshot: on the left you can see the hover effect (background is orange), on the right you can see how the effect vanishes if the cursor hits the text on the rectangle:

[image: comparison]

Thank you

Comment: Did you try text:hover + rect {fill: rgb(255,128,0);} ?

Comment: yes, but this of course only changes the color of the text

Comment: Only the color of the text? Hm, strange..

Comment: P.S. I meant your code plus my code.

Comment: Ah I see, thanks. Still having troubles, see ScottS suggestion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to make the text have pointer-events="none" so that it's ignored by the hover.

```
<g>
    <rect class="myclass" x="10" y="10" width="40" height="40" />
    <text x="30" y="40" font-family="Verdana" font-size="10" fill="blue" pointer-events="none">ESC</text>
</g>
```

Comment: Also possible to do in CSS, e.g `text { pointer-events:none }`.

Comment: Thanks! For me, this seems to be the best solution.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the hover is assigned to element that sits behind the text.  So when you're hovering over the text, you're technically NOT touching the background anymore.

My suggestion would be to apply the class to the parent  element, and assign the hover to that.

```
<g class="myclass">
    <rect x="10" y="10" width="40" height="40" />
    <text x="30" y="40" font-family="Verdana" font-size="10" fill="blue">ESC</text>
</g>
```

Now your CSS would look like this, to target the child "rect" element:

```
.myclass:hover rect {
    fill: rgb(255,128,0);
}
```

Comment: This should work assuming the `g` element is sized equal to the `rect` element (which in most cases would be), otherwise the hover could happen "prematurely" before actually entering the `rect` zone (in a case where the `g` had some `padding` or something else making it larger than `rect`).

Comment: This works, thanks. But like ScottS said, i have to take care of the elements' sizes